# Installing lintr for GitHub actions

Tags: r, github, github-actions

I want to adapt the [boilerplate code](https://github.com/r-lib/actions/blob/master/examples/lint.yaml) in the r-lib/actions repo to add a linting check to my (fake) package. I have my workflow yaml as follows:

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
      - master
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - main
      - master

name: lint

jobs:
  lint:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    defaults:
      run:
        working-directory: ./mystarwars
        
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - uses: r-lib/actions/setup-r@v1

      - name: Query dependencies
        run: |
          install.packages('remotes')
          saveRDS(remotes::dev_package_deps(dependencies = TRUE), "../.github/depends.Rds", version = 2)
          writeLines(sprintf("R-%i.%i", getRversion()$major, getRversion()$minor), "../.github/R-version")
        shell: Rscript {0}

      - name: Restore R package cache
        uses: actions/cache@v2
        with:
          path: ${{ env.R_LIBS_USER }}
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-${{ hashFiles('../.github/R-version') }}-1-${{ hashFiles('../.github/depends.Rds') }}
          restore-keys: ${{ runner.os }}-${{ hashFiles('../.github/R-version') }}-1-

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: |
          install.packages(c("remotes"))
          remotes::install_deps(dependencies = TRUE)
          install.packages(c("lintr"))
        shell: Rscript {0}

      - name: Install package
        run: R CMD INSTALL .

      - name: Lint
        run: lintr::lint_package()
        shell: Rscript {0}
```

However, I get errors when trying to install lintr in the "Install dependencies". This step fails (silently), so then when it reaches the "Lint" step it fails with `Error: Error in loadNamespace(x) : there is no package called ‘lintr’`.

This remains the case whether I use `install.packages(c("lintr"))` or `remotes::install_cran("lintr")`.

[HERE](https://pastebin.com/prZ5VTrq) is the full log of the "Install dependencies" step on GitHub Actions.

Comment: The first error in the log is that the system image you chose doesn't have the "libcurl4-openssl-dev" system dependency. The boilerplate code uses mac-os but you changed that to ubuntu-latest. Maybe see: https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/issues/37

Comment: Thank you! Adding the curl dependency fixed it